# Facebook ID message

Tags: facebook

I have made a web site app linked with Facebook and I have decided to host it myself using WAMP. I have a domain that is forwarding to my IP and in the Facebook app settings, I've changed the app domain and web site URL as my new domain. I have also changed the channel URL in my html files, but when I use anything on the site such as login, it throws up an error:

> "API Error Code: 191
> API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
> Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration."

Is this being shown because all the domain is doing is redirecting to my IP?

- Any advice would be much appreciated. (This is for a college project)

Answer (score 0):

If the domain is redirecting to an IP on your machine, and that it's the IP who's displayed in your address bar. e.g.: *127.0.0.1:8000/app.php*

Then you need to add this IP as the domain (and not the URL who's only redirecting to your IP)

Comment: It doesn't show the ip in the address bar, it maintains the domain name.

Comment: But when i've got the app domain setting set to eg. 127.0.0.1/index.html facebook says that it isn't a domain, any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you add the domain at two place: in at least one app (page tab, canvas) and in the allowed domain (text input near the app name)